# JavaScript ES6 Modules - looking for equivalent to window[functionNameString]()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, es6-modules

I'm converting my JavaScript code to ES6 modules for better modularity.

A common pattern in my code is to define a string that contains the name of a function:
`let nextMethodName = "aFunctionName";`

Then, sometime later, in a general event handler, I'll execute that function using:
`window[nextMethodName]();`

Now I'm trying to do the same kind of thing inside module code.

So, if the function I want to eventually execute is inside a module, I'll have:

`import * as myModule from "/JavaScript/myModule.js";`

I can execute my function directly:
`myModule.aFunctionName();`

but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to do something similar to
`window[myFunctionName]();`

myModule does not appear to be an object in window, so I can't do something as simple as:
`let nextMethodName = "myModule.aFunctionName";`

How can I pass the name of a function to be executed, or a reference to that function, to my event handler? This would seem to be a very simple question, but Mr. Google and I have not been getting anywhere useful.

Thanks!

Comment: first, `myModule` will **NOT** exist on `window` in a module in this case - that's not what import does- `let nextMethodName = "aFunctionName"; myModule[nextMethodName]();` - a more meaningful answer would be forthcoming if you showed your attempted usage in more detail

Comment: Couldn't you call the function as: `window[mModule.myFunctionName]();`?

Comment: @Yousaf no, that will not work.

Comment: Honestly I think there should be a completely different approach to making your tools available. That's the whole point of the module system.

Comment: @Pointy if `mModule.myFunctionName` evaluates to a function name, for example `"foo"`, then i would expect `window[myModule.myFunctionName]()` to work. What am i missing here?

Comment: Well for one thing imported modules do not end up as properties of `window` unless the code does that explicitly, which would be a pretty bad way of doing things.

Comment: No, window[myModule.myFunctionName]() doesn't work, because myModule does not exist as an object in window.

Comment: I had hoped that I could try something like: myModule[nextMethodName](); but myModule is undefined in this context. myModule doesn't really exist as an object: it just seems to be syntactic sugar to reference the objects that a module exports.

Comment: @Pointy yes ofcourse. I didn't mean to suggest that `myModule` will automatically become a property on the `window` object. It will work provided that `window` object already has a property with that name.

Comment: the main issue with `window[myModule.myFunctionName]()` is that it would try to execute `window["[object Object]"]()`

Comment: a more meaningful answer would be forthcoming if you showed your attempted usage in more detail - as it stands, it seems like an odd thing you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks for your comments Bravo. I've tried to pare this down to a trivial use case.  In my case, I have created an event handler that reacts asynchronously to things that my server has done (more specifically, it reacts to a property setter). When it's completed its tasks, I want it to call a function that is specified at run time. window["aFunctionName"]() is an easy way to accomplish this, although it relies on the function being an object in window.  It works quite well, but the namespace is huge, so I'd like to use modules to shrink the namespace.

Comment: This seems like a pretty common thing to do: "at this point in my code, I want to execute a function. I don't know which function to execute right now, but I will know at run time". I'm not that familiar with JavaScript, but it's like passing a closure in other languages, or passing a functional reference in other languages. Except that I can't pass a functional reference to a get property - I have to rely on that reference being somewhere in the namespace at execution time.

Comment: At this point, it appears that there may not be an elegant answer to my question. Is it possible that modules in JavaScript are not quite ready for prime time? What I've done is to create an object that lives inside window:  let nextFunction = myModule.myFunctionName;   I can test to see if typeof window[nextMethodName] === 'function' .. and if not, I can just call next Function().   It's a bit ugly, but at least it works whether my handler was called from module code, or from outside module code.

Comment: Using the global scope is a terrible idea for a lot of reasons. Ideally, you'd create a *very* small number of global symbols, and use those as places to keep your global methods.

Comment: Yes, Pointy, the whole point of this exercise is to tame the namespace, and avoid globals.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've come up with is to use a functional reference that's in the namespace of the event handler. For example:

`let nextFunction = myModule.myFunctionName;`

and in my event handler, which can be dispatched either from modules, or from legacy code that relies on window[functionName]:

```
    if (typeof window[nextMethodName] === 'function')
        window[nextMethodName]();
    else 
        if (typeof nextFunction === 'function')
            nextFunction();
```